# Apache Proxy should retry connections to domain with multiple IPs

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, httpd

I have a proxy server running Apache 2.4. It is used by clients to connect to `fcm.googleapis.com`.

The configuration is quite simple:

```
Listen 8099

ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off

<VirtualHost *:8099>

    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyVia off
    ProxyTimeout 30

    <Proxy *>
        Require ip XXX
        Require ip YYY
        Require local
    </Proxy>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog "logs/forwardproxy_error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/forwardproxy_access_log" combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

</VirtualHost>
```

`fcm.googleapis.com` is mapped to multiple IP addresses.

From an internet connected machine:

```
fcm.googleapis.com is an alias for googleapis.l.google.com.
googleapis.l.google.com has address 216.58.207.234
googleapis.l.google.com has address 172.217.20.42
googleapis.l.google.com has address 216.58.207.202
googleapis.l.google.com has address 172.217.22.170
googleapis.l.google.com has address 172.217.21.170
googleapis.l.google.com has address 216.58.211.10
googleapis.l.google.com has address 172.217.21.138
googleapis.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400f:806::200a
```

Due to some (network/firewall-related) reasons, some of the IP addresses above are not reachable from my Apache proxy (`ex. 172.217.0.0/16`) and some are reachable (`ex. 216.58.0.0/16`). However, given that the service behind `fcm.googleapis.com` should still be available since some IP segments remain available, it would not make sense that the proxy clients would get connection timeouts.

curl and wget tests:

```
[user@server ~]$ wget https://fcm.googleapis.com
--2019-08-16 11:50:30--  https://fcm.googleapis.com/
Connecting to proxyip:8099... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
[user@server ~]$ curl -X GET https://fcm.googleapis.com
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
[ansible@server ~]$
```

Update 1:
The proxy IP and port are correctly set on these clients (ex. `export http_proxy=http://proxyip:8099; export https_proxy=$http_proxy`). I know connections are reaching the proxy because some other sites (ex. Facebook) are reachable.

So my question is: how can I ensure that connections to `fcm.googleapis.com` would not fail? Where should it be fixed? On the Apache proxy (and if so, how?) or on the proxy clients?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you!